# Success.phtml - how to trigger affillate script based on product-ID ordered by customer?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, ecommerce-tracking, affiliate

First of all - I'm not a developer..I´ve tried google, but can't seem to find out how to do this..

I need to add a function to my success.phtml that triggers a spesific tracking script that I got from my affilate provider. 
I have two different tracking scripts, where the first script should be triggered if a customer purchased a product where the product ID matches one these ID's "19, 76, 84, 85, 86, 95" , and another script that should be triggered if the customer don't buy any of the mentioned products..

--
I've tried to add this to my success.phtml, but this obviously dosen't work. Could someone be an angel and help me sort this out?

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();

$sku = $ids = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  $p_ids[] = $item->getProductId();
}

$p_id = 19, 76, 84, 85, 86, 95;
?>

<?php if(in_array($p_id, $p_ids)){
   //run script 1
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://track.adtraction.com/t/t?t=1********************************************************"></script>
} else {
    //run script 2
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://track.adtraction.com/t/t?2********************************************************"></script> 
} 
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();

$found = false;
$affiliateProductIds = array(19, 76, 84, 85, 86, 95);

foreach($items as $item){
  if(in_array($item->getProductId(), $affiliateProductIds)){
     //if you need to send the product ids to the affiliate, they use an array instead of bool ($found) 
     $found = true;
  }
}
?>

<?php if($found) : ?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://track.adtraction.com/t/t?t=1********************************************************"></script>
<?php else : ?>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://track.adtraction.com/t/t?2********************************************************"></script> 
<?php endif;?>
```